# php curl emulate a browser?

Tags: php, curl

we are have next headers when we send post:

```
POST http://www.autonavigator.ru/dispatcher.pl HTTP/1.1
Host: www.autonavigator.ru
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 55
Origin: http://www.autonavigator.ru
X-Request: JSON
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.36
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://www.autonavigator.ru/my/offer_add/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: region_id=45; city_id=22; user_name=rora%40gmail.com; user_type=user; user_offer_count=1; user_message_count=0; user_no_confirm=1; session_id=WR9q4d41DgD7biTOOsMzgtXfJm83VFQn; USession=WR9q4d41DgD7biTOOsMzgtXfJm83VFQn; _ym_visorc_5781676=b

class=list&method=make&show_all=1&vehicle=car&type=used
```

*I would like emulate browser with curl.*

*For this i use next code:*

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.autonavigator.ru/dispatcher.pl');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.36"); 
$headers = array
(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate',
    'Accept-Charset: windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7'
); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.autonavigator.ru/my/offer_add/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'class=list&method=make&show_all=1&vehicle=car&type=used');

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

*But in result we get some errors(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWkdP.png):*

[image]

*Tell me please where error in code an how will be right ?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely like the content is gzipped, so you just need to do:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
```